# PHP Mysql - Use a variable as column name in Select statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database

I have month names as column names such as jan, feb, march, etc. in my table.
In my Form user needs to choose a month from drop down which I take the user's selection
as $month_name. 
I want to see the data in $month_name which is not 0.00.

When I echo $month_name I get: jan or feb or etc.

I used $month_name in my select statement but not working:
1st try not working:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM bookoff_monthly WHERE '.$month_name.' <> 0.00 AND year='$year' ";
```

2nd try not working:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM bookoff_monthly WHERE $month_name <> 0.00 AND year='$year' ";
```

****** but the following works but this isn't what I want:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM bookoff_monthly WHERE jan <> 0.00 AND year='$year' ";
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would consider properly escaped:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM bookoff_monthly WHERE `".$month_name."` <> 0.00 AND year='".$year."' ";
```

Notice that around `$month_name` you have the backticks in the statement, then double quotes (as the entire query is surrounded by them) then the PHP concatenation (`.`). You're better off thinking about it as a `string + variable + string ...` rather than a variable in a string. Same with the $year variable.

In your first statement you were close but you were using single quotes to break out of the string, but you can't do that if the string is contained in double quotes.

```
$var = "is a";

echo("This ".$var." string 'with quoted text'"); // This is a string 'with quoted text'

echo("This ".$var." string \"with quoted text\""); // This is a string "with quoted text"

echo('This '.$var.' string "with quoted text"'); // This is a string "with quoted text"

echo('This '.$var.' string \'with quoted text\''); // This is a string 'with quoted text'
```

Assuming your variables are in the correct format then this should work.

EDIT: As VMai says, because you are dealing in 3 letter month names, you will inevitably be using "DEC" or "dec" in this query, and that is a reserved word in MySQL so you **must** escape the name with backticks or the query will be misinterpreted.

Comment: You could add that escaping identifiers is in this case a must have because the column `DEC` will break unescaped queries. The cause: `DEC` is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL. $year can be used as is, but it would be better to use parameterized prepared statements instead. Note that one cannot use parameters for identifiers.

Comment: That's a good point! I always wrap column and table names in back-ticks for that reason

Comment: That is also true, but is outside the scope of this question

Comment: Note that the "quoted" still isn't escaped---the query is still vulnerable.  This will work **only** if `$month_name` has been quoted *as an identifier* and `$year` is quoted *as a literal*.  Since OP didn't perform any SQL protection at all, this *really* should be addressed in the answer.

Comment: He asked how to insert the variable correctly - not how to sanitize the input. If we address every concern with every question then none of the answers on this site would be specific enough. Plus OP only posted the query, so we have no idea what else has been done

Comment: Agree with the backticks.  Disagree with leaving the double quote. I'd just stay in the quote the whole time, since variables ate parsed within double quotes, and because its easier to see/read without concatenators. *are parsed

Comment: So I would recommend to use `$sql = "SELECT * FROM bookoff_monthly WHERE \`$month_name\` <> 0.00 AND year='?'";` in a prepared statement and checking `$month_name` against a whitelist.

Comment: When I use `".$month_name."` in select statement I get no result (no data). <br />

Comment: I'm not too concerned about the year, so I changed the statement to:

Comment: sql ="SELECT * FROM bookoff_monthly WHERE '".$month_name."' <> 0.00 ";

Comment: @php411: I understood your column names are jan, feb, mar, ..., nov, dec. Then your statement should return all rows of your table for those 12 values in your `$month_name` variable.

Comment: @ilovecode I would agree if SQL injections weren't the #1 cause for massive and widespread vulnerabilities and exploits.  I consider us ("us" being "professional programmers") to have the responsibility to put forth that type of education anytime we see it needs done.  An SQL query with variable interpolation in PHP is _always_ a bad thing... use the provided APIs to safely prepare parameterized queries and SQL injection "magically" disappears.

Answer (score 1):

As to the direct question:

The problem with #1 is that you are trying to mix single and double quotes. Assuming that $month_name = "jan", this will give you:

```
SELECT * FROM bookoff_monthly WHERE '.jan.' <> 0.00 AND year='$year'
```

As '.jan.' is not equal to 0.00, this won't find any records.

Your second one looks to me like it should work. You might try printing the resulting string to see what it's giving you. Perhaps you have additional characters you're not expecting in the month_name or something.

But in any case, this is just asking for SQL injection attacks. A hacker could, for example, fake out your input form and set jan="1+1=2; delete from bookoff_monthly where 1.00 ", and nowit will delete everything for the given year.

Plus any design that has you generating field names on the fly should be questioned right off the bat.

The right way to do this is to have a many-to-may relationship with one record for each month. Like create table bookoff_month (bookoff_id int, month char(3), amount decimal(7,2)). Then your query becomes select * from bookoff_monthly join bookoff_month on bookoff_month.bookoff_id=bookoff_monthly.bookoff_id where month=? and year=? and fill them in with a prepared statement, or at least wrap the parameters in a function that does proper escaping.

Answer (score -2):

`$sql = 'SELECT * FROM bookoff_monthly WHERE '.$month_name.' <> 0.00 AND year="'.$year.'"`

Comment: This answer, while it may work, is **extremely** poor form.  Neither the identifier nor the literal being embedded in the query is protected against injection.